# MySQL not using index when escaping character

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am experiencing strange behavior when using escaping `\` in my query. MySQL is for some reason ignoring my index. This only happens in production using `8.0.16`. If I only use single (`App\Models\Ad`), it actually uses the index.

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM media WHERE model_type = 'App\\Models\\Ad'
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | media |  | ALL | media_model_type_model_id_index,model_type_index |  |  |  | 60712 | 50.00 | Using where |

```sql
SHOW INDEXES FROM media
```

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| media | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 57722 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| media | 1 | media_model_type_model_id_index | 1 | model_type | A | 8 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| media | 1 | media_model_type_model_id_index | 2 | model_id | A | 29463 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |

```sql
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
| --- | --- |
| utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

One theory I have is that it might be due to the `model_type` column mainly consisting of the value `App\Models\Ad` 76% (45579/59816 rows).

Why is MySQL ignoring my index when escaping `\`?

Comment: Escaping is just syntax, it shouldn't have any effect on query processing. If it's not using the index, it means that there's no data that matches that string.

Comment: If you query for a different value that occurs on a small percentage of rows in the table, does it use the index? MySQL will skip an index if it estimates that the query condition will match a large portion of the table and end up reading most of the pages anyway.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, this was the reason. Thanks for the help! :)